# Web scraping from div, class and span elements

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I want to extract data from [S&P Down Jones Indices web site](http://www.espanol.spindices.com/). The relevant data is embedded in this code:

```html
<div class="indices-detail-container">
  <div id="all-indices-slider" class="slides" style="float: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -5px; margin: 0px; width: 6318px; height: 113px;">

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/dow-jones-sustainability-chile-index-clp" title="DJSI Chile" contentidentifier="2e9cb165-0cbf-4070-a5ef-dc20bf6219ba" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="Dow Jones Sustainability™ Chile Index (CLP)">DJSI Chile</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">943.76 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up ">0.07% ▲</span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-bvl-peru-general-index-pen" title="S&amp;P/BVL Peru General Index (PEN)" contentidentifier="cec2fa99-13f9-4bf5-9770-4832d86dc017" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/BVL Peru General Index (PEN)">S&amp;P/BVL Peru General Index ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">9,922.82 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  down ">-0.04% ▼ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-bvl-peru-select-index" title="S&amp;P/BVL Peru Select Index" contentidentifier="162ea564-b038-493c-a3bc-5f56bda60bb4" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/BVL Peru Select Index">S&amp;P/BVL Peru Select Index</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">188.02 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 0.18% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail last">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-bvl-lima-25-index-pen" title="S&amp;P/BVL LIMA 25 Index (PEN)" contentidentifier="12f6a899-f5f6-4c6f-9a82-9db3da8d2821" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/BVL LIMA 25 Index (PEN)">S&amp;P/BVL LIMA 25 Index (PEN)</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">13,153.1 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  down "> -0.3% ▼ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-bvl-mining-index-pen" title="S&amp;P/BVL Mining Index (PEN)" contentidentifier="2bef26d1-5720-457f-838a-761a176b06a6" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/BVL Mining Index (PEN)">S&amp;P/BVL Mining Index (PEN)</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">117.81 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 1.15% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-lac-40-us" title="S&amp;P Latin America 40" contentidentifier="41ac7d89-a7d8-49d7-8d15-ff9bbc22a17a" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P Latin America 40">S&amp;P Latin America 40</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">2,213.49 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  down "> -0.49% ▼ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/fixed-income/sp-valmer-mexico-government-cetes-index" title="S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico Government CETES Index" contentidentifier="d1973dbe-ce5e-4757-b5d5-face93abbb7c" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico Government CETES Index">S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">201.36 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 0.01% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail last no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-mila-andean-40-index" title="S&amp;P MILA Andean 40" contentidentifier="b5374c9e-85b3-44c1-a37e-dd1f8d3abb1b" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P MILA Andean 40">S&amp;P MILA Andean 40</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">439.28 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 0.41% ▲ </span>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="index-slide" style="margin-right: 5px;">

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/commodities/dow-jones-commodity-index" title="DJCI" contentidentifier="338b4dbf-d7eb-470b-9b17-8c713c4612ab" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="Dow Jones Commodity Index">DJCI</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">234.06 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  down "> -1.05% ▼ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-500" title="S&amp;P 500" contentidentifier="725e00f8-85c7-4fef-87f6-1c11be7f6517" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P 500®">S&amp;P 500</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">2,051.35 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  down "> -1.05% ▼ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-mila-pacific-alliance-composite" title="S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance Composite" contentidentifier="3baf0ead-3784-4daf-9333-2f32470ddb4e" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance Composite">S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">349.36 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 1.54% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail last">
     <h5><a href="/indices/commodities/sp-gsci" title="S&amp;P GSCI" contentidentifier="dd11d7c8-0c9b-492c-8242-1017e4d41c29" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P GSCI">S&amp;P GSCI</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">2,121.09 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  down ">-1.03% ▼ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-latin-america-bmi-us-dollar" title="S&amp;P Latin America BMI" contentidentifier="c9ba7da8-4dcb-4a7d-9a81-ae8497a9f1db" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P Latin America BMI">S&amp;P Latin America BMI</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">189.48 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 1.08% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-ifci-latin-america-price-index-in-us-dollar" title="S&amp;P/IFCI Latin America" contentidentifier="b22825f7-d873-4e96-818d-28036f7dba27" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/IFCI Latin America">S&amp;P/IFCI Latin America</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">1,228.91 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 0.35% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-latin-america-infrastructure-index" title="S&amp;P Latin America Infrastructure" contentidentifier="b3751332-cf1c-4fb2-8e46-733932ed6989" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P Latin America Infrastructure Index">S&amp;P Latin America ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">1,055.92 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 2.79% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail last no-bottom-border">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-latin-america-adr-index" title="S&amp;P Latin America ADR" contentidentifier="91c85053-fa63-448b-9b5f-7f34f0afa964" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P Latin America ADR Index">S&amp;P Latin America ADR</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">205.43 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 2.17% ▲ </span>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="index-slide" style="margin-right: 5px;">

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-mila-pacific-alliance-select" title="S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance Select" contentidentifier="5da0480d-e00f-4dd6-a99f-8c9d01dfe859" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance Select">S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">3,842.7 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 1.63% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/equity/sp-mila-pacific-alliance-completion-index" title="S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance Completion" contentidentifier="cb45f262-959e-4eab-b9e2-abddd4efc6e6" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance Completion">S&amp;P MILA Pacific Alliance ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">477.39 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 1.45% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail">
     <h5><a href="/indices/fixed-income/sp-valmer-mexico-government-international-1-year-ums-index" title="S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico Government International 1+ Year UMS Index" contentidentifier="6b29ea9c-3a43-4c09-94b5-a5fe93fac9b4" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico Government International 1+ Year UMS Index">S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">327.07 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 0.12% ▲ </span>
   </div>

   <div class="index-detail last">
     <h5><a href="/indices/fixed-income/sp-valmer-mexico-government-1-5-year-mbonos-index" title="S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico Government 1-5 Year MBONOS Index" contentidentifier="16d4060c-3a31-4efa-8c57-239c679bb779" contenttype="web-page" contenttitle="S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico Government 1-5 Year MBONOS Index">S&amp;P/Valmer Mexico ...</a></h5>
     <span class="return-value">244.56 </span>
     <span class="daily-change  up "> 0.05% ▲ </span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a big section that encapsulates the indices data, with `class` defined as `indices-detail-container`. Inside this section there are three sub sections, one defined with `class` `all-indices-slider` and the last two defined with `class` `index-slide`. The data I want to extract is inside these three sub sections and is contained in:

```
<div class="index-detail">
    ...
</div>
```

Specifically I want the `content title` and the `return-value` inside the `index-detail` classes. For example, for the first item I'd like:

> Title = "Dow Jones Sustainability™ Chile Index" or "DJSI Chile"
>
> Value= 943.76

I was thinking I could use the `contentidentifier` tag inside the heading element `<h5>`, however I don't know how to call the tag to discriminate between the indices.

So far I have:

```
Sub Dow_HistoricalData()

    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
    Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.espanol.spindices.com/", False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("all-indices-slider")

End Sub
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName()?

Comment: Are you open for other tool or just want to do in vba? because excel is not built for scraping and there are dedicated tool available. i can answer if you are willing to

Comment: @Vicky I used to do this with R but with the new software setup in my office we can't install anything and we are forced to use excel vba for everything.

Comment: @capm You didn't need to install software which requires Admin permission. See my answer now and you can export the output in excel as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

You have explained very well what you are after:

> I want the content title and the return-value inside the index-detail
>   classes

---

① `return-value` is a class so you can do:

```
.index-detail .return-value
```

[`"."` stands for className](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp), and [" ." means classNames within preceeding](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) i.e. get all return-value className elements contained within `.index-detail` classNames.

For the HTML shown you can abbreviate to `.return-value`.

---

② `contenttitle` is an attribute and needs slightly different syntax to select of:

```
.index-detail [contenttitle]
```

Which can be abbreviated, for shown HTML to: `[contenttitle]`.

---

Here is a sample view of both selectors:

① **.return-value**

[image: sample]

②  **[contenttitle]**

[image: Sample]

---

**VBA:**

So, how does this translate into VBA? Well, .document has a [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall) method. You created an instance of this with your `html` variable and populated it with

```
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
```

Assuming this returned the HTML you need, then you simply use:

```
Dim contentTitles As Object, returns As Object
Set contentTitles = html.querySelectorAll("[contenttitle]")
Set returns = html.querySelectorAll(".return-value")

Dim currentNode As Long
For currentNode = 0 To contentTitles.Length - 1
    Debug.Print contentTitles(currentNode).innerText
    'Debug.Print contentTitles.item(currentNode).innerText '<==Or potentially this syntax
    Debug.Print returns(currentNode).innerText
    'Debug.Print returns.item(currentNode).innerText '<==Or potentially this syntax
Next currentNode
```

Note:

The returned objects are [static nodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). The collection of matching items. You traverse the length of these, which are matching (0 to 19 indices), and access the text via the `.innerText` property.